# Custom HTML form templating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, xslt, asp.net-web-api, jsrender

I have a requirement where I need to convert a html form to a PDF document using a service.
The purpose of this service would be to just convert a given set of data in XML and apply to a custom HTML template form.
Normally the way I would have done this was to using XSL to style the XML data to the required template into HTML form then convert PDF and then return the result using a WCF service.

However, in the effort of learning something new I was thinking of using JSRender templating to produce the required HTML form and then convert to PDF using a REST service using ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WEB API.
Now my question is related to whether what I suggest is possible:
- To use JSRender to do the custom form templating, I will need to pass the XML data to the REST service as part of the request.
- XML data then is bound to the templates using JSRender.

The problem is I would assume I can't just XML to a HTML page and then bind the data to the templates. I was under the impression it would be the other way around, I would have to make a AJAX request from the HTML form and bind to the resultant JSON. Could I somehow pass in XML to HTML form and then bind it to the templates?

If what I want is possible, should I even use Web API or stick with MVC forms?
Or should I not even bother with the whole JSREnder approach and just use the XML-XSLT approach?

Would be nice to get feedback and advice, if you need any more detail then let me know...

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your quesiton, but it seems like you are using HTML forms to *display* data, rather than to *accept* input data.  This is not what HTML forms are for.  If you want to display data coming from a web service, jsRender is great for that, but if you are using it to display the data your getting, this is not an application for either technology.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your understanding is pretty much correct.

Comment: I wanted to provide the data to for the databinding by JSRender, so what I was trying to do was almost inject the HTML form on load with the required data rather than having to load the HTML form first then using a AJAX WS request to get the data. Hope it makes sense but looks like I probably will have to do the latter anyway since what I was trying to do initially doesn't seem to make much sense :). I.e, call the MVC view which inturn will call a AJAX service to get the data using JSON then bind to ouput the form and then return HTML form as a string .

Comment: jsRender is not meant for databinding.  It is meant for one-way DOM rendering.  If you need databinding, check out KnockOut.js (http://knockoutjs.com/) It does everything you are looking for, including templating.  And for what it's worth, the explanation you just gave of your approach is exaclty what I would do.  It's the cleanest approach.

Comment: Thank you wtfsven, nice to have the approcach at least sanity tested :), will get on with it and let you know how I get on. Also as you mentioned, only need one way binding so will stick with JSRender.